# Traversing two steps back to change class - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a link whose parent is two steps away. When I click the link I want to change the distant parents class.

Example html:

```
<div class="classA">
    <div class="linkHolder">
        <a href="#" id="clickMe">hello</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when clicking the link I want to change the parent -> parent class from classA to classB

This is what I'm trying but has no effect:

```
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
    $(this).prevUntil('classA').removeClass('classA').addClass('classB');
});
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `prevUntil` looks at *previous siblings* - ie elements on the same level

Comment: Ahh, ok, thanks for that, it explains everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.classA').toggleClass('classA classB');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8k69/)

note: it doesn't change the class back once clicked again or anything like that, as it's not specified in the question.

Comment: Or **[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/r8k69/1/)** if you want to toggle between classA and classB on successive clicks.